# How can I open subscription page on careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, jobs

I recieve job notification email and there is a link to my subscription which points to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/subscribe

But I cannot browse to this page using the web careers.stackoverflow.com interface itself.

How can I browse to subscrition page from the home page of careers.stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Right there.]

Click that little envelope right there.

Comment: Thank you! I look for it in `my profile` so it cannot be done. It's in `search job` tab instead.